# Saving the responses as struct from the GUI in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, response

I supposed to assign the entered strings or chosen values  to a struct in the callback functions.  I have something like below but I cannot embed it into function. In command window, matlab returns me some numerical values rather than responses

% subject.name = NameAns
% subject.gender = GenderAns

```
  function b

    d = dialog('Position',[300 300 300 300],'Name','My Dialog');


    NameAns = uicontrol('Parent', d,...
            'Style', 'edit',...
            'String','Type Your Name',...
            'position', [70 260 100 20] )



    GenderAns = uicontrol('Parent', d,...
                    'Style', 'popup', 'String', {'female','male', 'other'},...
                    'Position', [70 230 90 20 ])

    uicontrol('Parent', d, 'Style', 'pushbutton',...
        'String', 'OK',...
        'Position', [90, 90, 110, 30],...
        'FontSize',18,'Callback',@OKCallBack);


    function ConfCallBack(source,eventdata)
            disp(get(source,'Value'));

     subject.name = NameAns
    subject.gender = GenderAns

             uiwait (d)
    end

        function OKCallBack(source,eventdata)
            close(d)
        end

    end
```

Comment: You have to get the `String` value from `NameAns` and `GenderAns`. Right now you're just storing the `uicontrol` objects...

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indentation of your code.